# component object is null ,this object used by autowired annotaiotion

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have to use a component, that is a netty server class.

I marked this class as a component and when trying to use from this object I code a field that marked via auto wired annotation.

I check this field a some where of my code, as a sample main method of my application by containsbean method.

This method return null!!!

My code is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = "com.brtech.*")
public class UapApplication {

@Autowired
private static NettyServer nettyServer;

public static void main(String[] args) {


ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(UapApplication.class, args);
System.out.println(context.containsBean("serverbean"));
}
}


@Component("serverbran")
public class NettyServer extends Thread {}
```

Comment: Not sure about Sprint Boot, but i guess you have to initialize the nettyServer, such as nettyServer = new NettyServer(); Hope this may help

Comment: @CyrusLeung not in the least. that's what autowiring is all about

Comment: @user3111321 why do you try to have all this in your application class?

Comment: @Stultuske oh my bad, thanks for the comment, gonna read the autowiring document now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is obvious - spelling. Check bean names: it's declared as "serverbran" and you're asking context about "serverbean" which is not declared. 
Another problem with your code is that `@Autowired` is not working for `static` fields, so injection will not happen here.